# PowerShell - Manage builds

Tags: powershell

I have a long script that uses in variables that can be chosen by a function, The goal is to know what the user choose and add 1 to the number at the end. I want to read from an external file (text/xml) the latest version and add 1 to it and after the user choose the version to work on I need to update the external file with the new number for the next run.
For an example:
The externa file will hold the following: (Don't know if the $ is needed)

```
$ReleaseVersion1 = "8.5.34.31.4"    
$ReleaseVersion2 = "8.5.34.35.4"    
$ReleaseVersion3 = "8.6.22.607.8"   
$ReleaseVersion4 = "8.6.22.2000.8"
```

The user run the script and choose to work with version 8.6.22.607 (This is what the UI shows)
We need to get the right version from the external file and put in $ReleaseVersion3 with value 8.6.22.607.9 (In this case all the rest should not changed)
Now we need to right the new value 8.6.22.607.9 to the external file for the next run

Here is the function from the script:

```
function ChooseVersion()
{
$ReleaseVersion1 = "8.5.34.31.4"    
$ReleaseVersion2 = "8.5.34.35.4"    
$ReleaseVersion3 = "8.6.22.607.8"   
$ReleaseVersion4 = "8.6.22.2000.8"  


$Sourceversion1 = "$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\8.5.34.31"
$Sourceversion2 = "$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\8.5.34.35"
$Sourceversion3 = "$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\8.6.22.607"
$Sourceversion4 = "$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\8.6.22.2000"
 
$Versions = @()
$Versions += "ReleaseVersion;Sourceversion;Versionlocationforpatches;Versionlocationforcabs;LinkForVersion;VersionNumber;buildver;PipelineID;xmlFilePath;ReleaseBuildVer"
$Versions += "$ReleaseVersion1;$Sourceversion1;$Sourceversion1\Installer\Patches;$Sourceversion1\Installer;\\bandit.com\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.5 RingOne\$ReleaseVersion1;8.5.34.31;8.5.34.31;18710;$Sourceversion1\BuildDescription.xml;$ReleaseVersion1"
$Versions += "$ReleaseVersion2;$Sourceversion2;$Sourceversion2\Installer\Patches;$Sourceversion2\Installer;\\bandit.com\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.5 RingOne\$ReleaseVersion2;8.5.34.35_Federal;8.5.34.35;18713;$Sourceversion2\BuildDescription.xml;$ReleaseVersion2"
$Versions += "$ReleaseVersion3;$Sourceversion3;$Sourceversion3\Installer\Patches;$Sourceversion3\Installer;\\bandit.com\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.6 RingOne\$ReleaseVersion3;8.6.22.607;8.6.22.607;18650;$Sourceversion3\BuildDescription.xml;$ReleaseVersion3"
$Versions += "$ReleaseVersion4;$Sourceversion4;$Sourceversion4\Installer\Patches;$Sourceversion4\Installer;\\bandit.com\global\builds\Releases\RingOne Builds\8.6 RingOne\$ReleaseVersion4;8.6.22.2000_Federal;8.6.22.2000;18667;$Sourceversion4\BuildDescription.xml;$ReleaseVersion4"

$Versions = $Versions | ConvertFrom-CSV -Del ";"
#$Versions
#do {$VersionToUse = ($Versions | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Select version to use").VersionNumber} while (-not $VersionToUse)
do {$VersionToUse = $Versions.VersionNumber | Out-Gridview -Title "Choose version for initialization" -PassThru } while ($Versions.VersionNumber -notcontains $VersionToUse)
#$VersionToUse = $Versions.buildver | Out-Gridview -Title "Choose version" -PassThru

$Versionlocationforpatches = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).Versionlocationforpatches
$Versionlocationforcabs = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).Versionlocationforcabs
$ReleaseVersion = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).ReleaseVersion
$Sourceversion = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).Sourceversion
$LinkForVersion = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).LinkForVersion
$VersionNumber = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).VersionNumber
$buildver = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).buildver
$PipelineID = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).PipelineID
$xmlFilePath = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).xmlFilePath
$ReleaseBuildVer = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).ReleaseBuildVer

Write-host "You decided to initialize parameters for version '$VersionToUse'" -ForegroundColor Cyan}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking for here. Are you hoping to write a PowerShell script that can rewrite and update the script you've posted, or are you asking how to better structure the current script so that a manual update of the version/build numbers becomes easier?

Comment: You are right. I want to update this script

Comment: Please be clear: Update it with another script, or update it to be easier to manually update?

Comment: I want to add an additional code inside the function, No need another script. Every run of the script leads to add a number at the end of the version that the user choose

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to get rid of your repeated code by storing the version numbers in a file. Here's what I recommend - use a basic text file of your version numbers, one per line:

```
8.5.34.31.4
8.5.34.35.4
8.6.22.607.8
8.6.22.2000.8
```

And this example should cover what you're doing in your question:

```
# import list of version numbers from file, one per line
$versionList = Get-Content '\\server\share\versions.txt'

# instead of creating a csv string, build a hash table for each version 
# be sure to add the rest of the properties you want
$versions = foreach ($version in $versionList) {
  [pscustomobject]@{
    ReleaseVersion = $version
    Sourceversion = "$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\$version"
    Versionlocationforpatches = "$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\$version\Installer\Patches"
    Versionlocationforcabs = "$SharedDriveFolderPath\Versions\$version\Installer"
    # etc...
  }
}

# ask user for version to intialize
$VersionNumberToUse = $Versions.ReleaseVersion | Out-Gridview -Title "Choose version for initialization" -PassThru 
# save all the properties to one variable:
$VersionToUse = $versions | Where ReleaseVersion -eq $VersionNumberToUse
Write-host "You decided to initialize parameters for version '$($VersionNumberToUse)'" -ForegroundColor Cyan

# To create a new version number, convert the chosen version string to int array
[int[]]$versionArray = $VersionToUse.ReleaseVersion -split '\.'
# then increment last index
$versionArray[-1] = $versionArray[-1] + 1
$NewVersionNumber = $versionArray -join '.'
Write-host "New version number is '$NewVersionNumber'" -ForegroundColor Cyan

# to add new version number to to version list file:
$NewVersionNumber | Out-File '\\server\share\versions.txt' -Append

# edit: example of setting variables - can just use $VersionToUse properties:
$Versionlocationforpatches = $VersionToUse.Versionlocationforpatches
$Versionlocationforcabs    = $VersionToUse.Versionlocationforcabs
# etc...
```

What I meant by "replace your CSV steps" is that using a hash table accomplishes the same thing, without needing to format your strings into a csv in your script. I did not add all 10 or so properties/variables, just enough to show how it works. For example, here's the output of my `$versions`:

```
PS C:\Users\me> $versions

ReleaseVersion Sourceversion                               Versionlocationforpatches                     
-------------- -------------                               -------------------------                     
8.5.34.31.4    \\server\share\path\Versions\8.5.34.31.4   \\server\share\path\\Versions\8.5.34.31.4\I...
8.5.34.35.4    \\server\share\path\Versions\8.5.34.35.4   \\server\share\path\\Versions\8.5.34.35.4\I...
8.6.22.607.8   \\server\share\path\Versions\8.6.22.607.8  \\server\share\path\\Versions\8.6.22.607.8\...
8.6.22.2000.8  \\server\share\path\Versions\8.6.22.2000.8 \\server\share\path\\Versions\8.6.22.2000.8...
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the answer. What does it means to replace the CSV?
What about all the variables like: I need them to the rest of the script

$Versionlocationforpatches = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).Versionlocationforpatches
$Versionlocationforcabs = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).Versionlocationforcabs
$ReleaseVersion = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).ReleaseVersion

Maybe you can combine my question and your answer please

Comment: What about all the $Sourceversion1 each one has another path and it is very important. Without the csv it’s looks very bad. Can you edit your answer please?

Comment: @Bandit I've updated my answer - hopefully it makes more sense to you this way

Comment: I am very sorry, currently the user can see in the UI only the version to choose and not all the information. Can you edit my function in your answer? I don’t know what I need to delete and what should stay.  What about all the properties like PipelineID = ($Versions | where {$_.VersionNumber -eq $VersionToUse}).PipelineID and all the global. It will be more easier to change my function with your changes with the same display as was before. Thanks

Comment: Except the way to store the numbers and get them from the external file the original function cannot stay as is?

Comment: @Bandit I edited the gridview to only show the version number.  Many of your properties are hardcoded into your script - like where should `PipelineID` come from if you add new versions to your file? I can only guess. Maybe you should just put **all** those properties into a csv file instead of using a script to generate them at all

Comment: All parameters should be in the external file? I am really try to understand

Comment: I started to insert the variables but I have a big problem
Some of them are general but for example each PipelineID should have a different number and I need to write PipelineID= # 
buildver should be 8.5.34.31 without the .4 an the end and 8.6.22.607
LinkForVersion should be different for each version. How you can solve this?

Comment: The user should choose VersionNumber ($VersionNumberToUse = $Versions.VersionNumber | Out-Gridview -Title "Choose version for initialization" -PassThru). and here its a different variable from the file (ReleaseVersion)
[int[]]$versionArray = $VersionToUse.ReleaseVersion -split '\.'

Comment: In addition to all the issues this is what happen after one run
8.5.34.31.4
8.5.34.35.4
8.6.22.607.8
8.6.22.2000.8
 
 8 . 6 . 2 2 . 6 0 7 . 9

It should replace the old one